# Why there are some gaps between img with 25% width in a flex div when using mobile phone?

Tags: css, image, mobile, width

Sorry for my poor English. The code may describe better.

```
    #wrapper{
       display:flex;
    }
    #wrapper img{
       width:25%;
    }


  <div id="wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.hellocoolguy.com/t/1.png" />
    <img src="https://www.hellocoolguy.com/t/2.png" />
    <img src="https://www.hellocoolguy.com/t/3.png" />
    <img src="https://www.hellocoolguy.com/t/4.png" />
</div>
```

I have a div#wrapper using display:flex, the img has 25% width, so the images can tile in a row.
It's ok in desktop browser, but in some mobile phones (or using chrome's DevTools to simulate), I can see gap between some images like below:
[image: gaps between images]

Some gaps seem to appear/disappear when I change the wrapper width. And it seems only happen on mobile. Desktop browsers (without chrome's DevTools to simulate mobile phones) always show the right result.
What's more, I found it would be ok if I use something like codepen ([the code here](https://codepen.io/coolguy001tv/pen/JjPmJvW)). When using codepen it's even ok with simulating mobile phone using chrome's DevTools.

I don't know how to modify my code to let mobile phones show properly.

You may see it directly from your mobile phone [here](http://hellocoolguy.com/t/t.html)

Edited on 2019.09.27
**This is happening in Wechat browser (using X5 browser as its core)** , and this may be a round pixel rendering question/bug.

Finally:
**Thanks for everyone who've helped. It has been still not resolved but I shall end it for it has cost us such a long time.**

Comment: Did you reload the page after switching to mobile device in chrome dev tools ? Sometimes it does not manage the transition between desktop and mobile smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But reload can not solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see the problem on ios, which platform are you checking it on? Also adding `object-fit: contain` to img styling may help.

Comment: @mulsun I am using OnePlus 6 with Android 9. object-fit: contain seems not to solve the problem. However, thanks for the suggestion. Besides, one of my friend who's using iPhone can not see the problem, either. It may be related to android.

Comment: Can you try font-size: 0 on #wrapper, i had a look, it should be related to that spacing.

Comment: Ouch, font-size:0 on #wrapper still can't help. And according to the answer below, I think this may be a problem related with X5 browser which is used by WeChat and some default android browsers in China. However, chrome always shows ok.

Comment: Hi @CoolGuy, I may be able to help you, but before I waste my own time. Can you clarify if you want to have four images side by side, or if you would like four div's with background images, I see people discussing both. Thanks, Jason.

Comment: @JasonIsMyName I want 4 images side by side.  Besides, 4 div with background imges is acceptable, too.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to some discrepancies in pixel rounding.

To ensure the pixels are rounded correctly add the following in your `head` tags:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

It's likely that Codepen automatically add this tag which is why you are unable to reproduce the issue on there.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But with the meta you mentioned, or using meta like this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">` can not solve my problem. Besides, I add object-fit: contain to img styling , it helps not, either.  And It seems not happen on ios.

Comment: @CoolGuy Interesting... I'm using Chrome on an Honor play and I can't see the problem on your site anymore. What browser are you using and can you try it in another one to see if it happens in that one too?

Comment: In my mobile phone, Chrome has no problem, but the default browser and the WeChat browser show not ok. However, my users are all using WeChat, so I have to fix it. Default browser and the WeChat browser both use X5 browser. Maybe it's a problem with X5?

Comment: Hmm, not going to lie, that isn't a browser I am familiar with and I'm not able to find much info about it. It is possible that it's a quirk with this browser if it seems to work in all others you've tested. If this is the case do you need to use `flex` or could you use another method like `float`?

Comment: I modified the code with one flex row and one float row, and unfortunately they both show wrong. I do think this may be a problem in pixel rounding. However, if you have any ideas, plz tell me, any hacks are welcome for me to try. If there're none, I may try to add some negative margins like 0.5px to bypass this problem.

Comment: @CoolGuy Just a thought, if you replace the images with `div`s that have a background colour on them do you still get the 1 pixel line between them?

Comment: That's weired, with background image, even chrome shows wrong, u may see the demo [here](http://hellocoolguy.com/t/t.html), which row1 is display:flex, row2 is div with background-image: `background-size:100% 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;`. I found  something interesting:  1) current width is 321px, if I modify width to 320px, chrome shows ok; 2) remove `background-repeat: no-repeat`, no matter what width the wrapper is, chrome shows ok. 3) background-color is always ok no matter what width is.

Comment: It definitely seems like a rounding issue, but it looks like you may have come across a solution by using `background-repeat: round;` or `background-repeat: repeat;`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just find that it seems that the browser has bug rendering the 25% width div. Even if I just set background-color, the gap is still here. See demo [here](https://www.hellocoolguy.com/t/t2.html) . It's of course ok in chrome, but it shows the gap in this disgusting x5 browser.

Comment: Hmm, I feel there maybe a fix but I'm afraid I'm not of much help as I can't see the issue in the browsers I have access to. If you swap the images with different ones do you still see the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by swapping the images with different ones? So you think this may be a problem with image itself instead of the div?

Comment: It's a long shot as the images look ok to me, but I have seen it before where there is a line of semi transparent pixels in the image which can misbehave when resized.

Comment: I open the image with photoshop and no transparent pixels are founded. However, thanks for all the time you've helped.

Comment: I appreciate you awarding the bounty to me, sorry I was unable to get to the root of your issue. I'll mull it over and update my answer if I can think of anything else, but without access to the browser it makes it difficult to debug.

Comment: Thanks, any ideas are always welcome. Although problem is not resolved, you help me much more than anyone else( though they still help me a lot). You are just worth the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-size : cover`

It will remove the space by cover your div with

[the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: Thanks. Cover doesn't help for this strange wechat browser, either.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
#wrapper .img { 
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:25%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a rendering bug.

When you add `background-position: right;` or `background-position: left;` you see the problem on the other side of the your element. 
So the bug is that your background image with the width of 100% just is not enough to fill the box.

> So you could use `background-size: 101% 100%;` to fix this bug. (Or
>   maybe 100.9% instead of 101%).

Another solution (in my opinion the better one) would be adding the same image in one box as a second background-image, but just placed on the other side.

> ```
> background-image: url(sameimage.png), url(sameimage.png);
> background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
> background-position: left top, right bottom;
> background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
> ```

The first background-image will be placed at the left-top-corner and the second one will be at the right-bottom-corner of your element.

In the worst case you will still have some pixels left and need to add the same image at each corner... (`background-position: left top, left right, bottom left, bottom right;`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But it doesn't help even if I set background-size:110% 110%. the gap is still there. It seems that this disgusting X5 browser has something wrong when rendering the 25% width div. Actually I just find that even if I just set background-color, I can still see the gap.So it seems that the 25% width div actually has width less than 25% width.